# Is forced organ donation widespread in China? (强制摘取犯器官的行为已经实施了?)

Tags: china, surgery

On December 10, 2018, Sir Geoffrey Nice made the following statement:

> The Tribunal’s members are all certain – unanimously, and sure beyond reasonable doubt – that in China forced organ harvesting from prisoners of conscience has been practised for a substantial period of time involving a very substantial number of victims.
>
> 作为本法庭成员，我们都一致确信，可以排除任何合理怀疑而认定，在中国，强制摘取良心犯器官的行为已经实施了相当长的一段时间，涉及到很大数量的受害者。我们将在最终判决中申明这种做法是否犯下国际罪行。
>
> https://chinatribunal.com/interim-judgement/

Is China doing this?